How to view operator norms on open-system representation of quantum channels
I know how the operator norms $\| X\|_{1}$,$\| X\|_{2}$, and $\| X\|_{\infty}$ are defined for  any operator $X\in B(\mathcal{H})$. My question is about how to view$\| T(X)\|_{1}$,$\| T(X)\|_{2}$, and $\| T(X)\|_{\infty}$, when T is a quantum channel.
Espescially when we use the open-system representation $T(X)=Tr_{AE}(U(X\otimes |\psi_{AE}\rangle\langle\psi_{AE}|))U^{\dagger})$.
For the 1-norm my intuition is:
I assume that since T is CP, it is self-adjoint. So for example the one norm becomes:
$$\| T(X)\|_{1} =\| Tr_{AE}(U(X\otimes |\psi_{AE}\rangle\langle\psi_{AE}|))U^{\dagger})\|_{1}=Tr(Tr_{AE}(U(X\otimes |\psi_{AE}\rangle\langle\psi_{AE}|))U^{\dagger}))=Tr(U(X\otimes |\psi_{AE}\rangle\langle\psi_{AE}|))U^{\dagger})=Tr(X\otimes |\psi_{AE}\rangle\langle\psi_{AE}|)=Tr(X)Tr(|\psi_{AE}\rangle\langle\psi_{AE}|)=Tr(X).
$$
But for the 2-norm and sup-norm I have no idea.
PS:
The question stems from trying to show
$\|T(X)\|_{1}\leq \|X\|_{1}$ using open system representation, and then if this also holds for the 2 and the sup-norm.

First, let us prove that every quantum channel is trace-norm contractive using the unitary Stinespring representation. For this we need the following lemma.

Lemma. For all $m,n\in\mathbb N$ and all $Z\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}\otimes\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ it holds that $\|{\rm tr}_2(Z)\|_1\leq\|Z\|_1$.

Proof. The easiest way to show this is to go via the adjoint channel/dual channel, that is, the fact that ${\rm tr}({\rm tr}_2(Z)Y)={\rm tr}(Z(Y\otimes{\bf1}))$ for all $Z\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}\otimes\mathbb C^{m\times m}$, $Y\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$. This simplifies the norm computation by the duality of the trace norm and the $\infty$-norm:
\begin{align*}
\|{\rm tr}_2(Z)\|_1&={\rm sup}_{Y\in\mathbb C^{m\times m},\|Y\|_\infty=1}|{\rm tr}({\rm tr}_2(Z)Y) )|\\
&={\rm sup}_{Y\in\mathbb C^{m\times m},\|Y\|_\infty=1}|{\rm tr}(Z(Y\otimes{\bf1}))|\\
&\leq{\rm sup}_{Y\in\mathbb C^{m\times m},\|Y\|_\infty=1}\|Z\|_1\|Y\otimes{\bf1}\|_\infty\\
&={\rm sup}_{Y\in\mathbb C^{m\times m},\|Y\|_\infty=1}\|Z\|_1\|Y\|_\infty\|{\bf1}\|_\infty=\|Z\|_1\,.
\end{align*}
In the second-to-last line we used this inequality and in the last line we used that the $\infty$-norm factorizes under tensor products. $\square$
With this the statement we want to prove follows at once; for all $X\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$, all states $\omega\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ and all unitaries $U\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}\otimes\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ we compute
\begin{align*}
\|{\rm tr}_2(U( X\otimes\omega )U^*)\|_1&\leq \|U( X\otimes\omega )U^*\|_1\\
&=\|X\otimes\omega\|_1\\
&=\|X\|_1\|\omega\|_1\\
&=\|X\|_1{\rm tr}(\omega)=\|X\|_1\,.
\end{align*}
In the second step we used that the trace norm is invariant under unitary channels (because the singular values do not change) and in the last line we used that because $\omega\geq 0$ its trace norm is equal to its trace (obvious from the definition of $\|\cdot\|_1$).
One can re-write this result in terms of superoperator-norms as $\|T\|_{1\to 1}\leq 1$ for all channels $T$ where  $\|T\|_{1\to 1}:=\sup_{\|X\|_1=1}\|T(X)\|_1$; in fact because every channel has a fixed point one even gets $\|T\|_{1\to 1}=1$ for all channels.

The follow-up question now is whether this result continues to hold if the underlying trace norm is replaced by another norm. For this one defines the general Schatten $p$-norm as $$\|X\|_p:=\big({\rm tr}((X^\dagger X)^{p/2})\big)^{1/p}$$---or, equivalently, $\|X\|_p:=(\sum_j\sigma_j(X)^p)^{1/p}$ where $\sigma_j(X)$ are the singular values of $X$---as well as the corresponding operator norm $\|\Phi\|_{p\to p}:=\sup_{\|X\|_p=1}\|\Phi(X)\|_p$. Note that this Schatten-$p$ norm is the natural generalization of $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ to other indices.
In this language, asking whether $\|T(X)\|_p\leq\|X\|_p$ for all $X$ is equivalent to $\|T\|_{p\to p}\leq 1$ ("$T$ is $p$-norm contractive"). Indeed, one can characterize when this is the case: as shown in this paper (arXiv) the following statements are equivalent:

$\Phi$ is unital, i.e. $\Phi({\bf1})={\bf1}$
$\|\Phi\|_{p\to p}=1$ for all $p\in[1,\infty]$
$\|\Phi\|_{p\to p}=1$ for some $p\in(1,\infty]$

In other words:

For all channels that are not unital and all $p>1$ there exists $X$ such that $\|T(X)\|_p>\|X\|_p$.


I didn't find it that enlightening, could you please elaborate?

@PinkElephants Elaborate on what exactly, is there something you don't understand or rather: in your opinion what aspect is missing form this answer? In the current version I show that, in general, channels do not satisfy $|T(X)|_2\leq|X|_2$ (actually: $|T(X)|_p\leq|X|_p$, $p>1$) for all $X$ meaning any proof attempt is futile. If there's something else you want to know about please let me know and I*ll gladly try to help out!

I think my confusion stems from the fact that the proof uses the Hahn-decompositions and not the open open-system repr. aswell as we have end up with a equality and not an inequality. And also i still dont see how we define $|()|_{p}$ ?

@PinkElephants Got it, I adjusted my answer accordingly. Hope this helps!

Thank you very much. What do you mean by $Tr_{2}$? Is it the partial trace to the second space?

Ah indeed that's what I meant; I forgot to adopt your ${\rm tr}_{AE}$ notation, sorry!
